# Bug fixing workflow with Nuget

Tags: .net, nuget

Currently our project use project reference to projects shared across multiple products. We are going to start using Nuget for package management. 
I'm wondering about best practices for typical development workflows - one of them is bug fixing in shared code.

Current workflow for bug fixing is very simple - use debugger to identify root cause of the bug (we can set breakpoints in shared code, and debug into shared methods, etc), make required changes in shared code to fix bug, rebuild solution, verify that all bug is fixed, and than check in changes in source control.

1. How will this workflow be changed if we start using Nuget?
2. Is it required to set up symbol source and publish debug symbols to be able to debug shared code?
3. How will verification part be changed?
4. Should we manually copy newly built shared binaries with potential bug fix into the "packages" folder for verification before check in?

Answer (score 1):

1. It will change as per the below responses.
2. Yes. You can either use our product [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) which includes this built-in, or set up your own server with [NuPeek](https://bitbucket.org/thinkbeforecoding/nupeek). To set this up in Visual Studio, we've created a guide for that here: http://inedo.com/support/kb/1036/using-progets-symbol-server
3. This part will cause you a little hassle, especially if you are lacking an automated build/release process. You will need at least 1 private repository to house these pre-release packages. Since ideally you will separate out the libraries into their own projects without sharing code, you may have to check-in the code to your CI system and have it automatically publish your package to a private repository, then pull the latest NuGet package from your repository into the project you want to verify the bug fix against. Once it's been verified, you can either create another version that's no longer pre-release, or push the package to the primary "Release" feed.
4. If this works for you, I don't see why you couldn't. However, with automation in place, it's actually easier just to check-in first and let your build/release tool handle everything, then update with a NuGet client as any consumer of the package would do - this way it also updates your packages.config file to the appropriate version.