# NuGet Packages, Active Development and References

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

We have 1 solution that contains all of our shared assemblies.  Currently we are referencing these assemblies based on relative path (../../../../../SharedSolution/bin).  It would be nice to create a nuget package (or a few based on various dependencies) to reference these assemblies so I can get easily update and I don't have to worry about having the exact same directory structure as everyone else on the team and all the other benefits of nuget.

However, let's say that when I'm working in my ProjectASolution, I realize that I need to make a change or add a shared class to SharedSolution.  In my ProjectASolution if I have referenced the assemblies from SharedSolution with a nuget package, but ***I want to test my changes to SharedSolution before committing them, is the only way to copy the assemblies from the SharedSolution bin to ProjectASolution's packages folder?***

Since we are frequently editing classes in SharedSolution, I'm beginning to think that nuget might not be the right way to share these assemblies.

Another possible solution is to add the projects from SharedSolution as links to any of my ProjectSolutions that need to reference them.  Is this a better alternative?

Is there a better way to share these assemblies than relative path?  ***Is there an easy way to test changes made on a dev machine to a nuget package?***

Comment: Check out this similar question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a pre-release package. Only developers who set their nuget to use pre-release packages will see them, everyone else will be still using the latest stable.

A good explanation and How-To can be found on the [NuGet Pre-Release Package](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pre-Release%20Packages) page.

To address the questions you raised in your comment:

You can build nuget packages locally, based on the .nuspec file which is usually next to the .nupkg file in the packages folder. You can use [NuGet Package Explorer](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864) to do so in a GUI.

To distribute them, you can store the pre-release packages on a network folder. Any developer interested in the pre-release package can add this network folder to their nuget sources and can then use the Visual Studio-integrated nuget as usual. Or you can just copy them the .nupkg file.

Comment: Our current process is to create the nuget package from TFS (this is done by the release manager/buildmaster).  Could a developer create a nuget package from the code locally on their machine as a pre-release?  Would we have to at least create a shelveset in TFS?  Currently developers don't have access to write to the machine that is hosting the nuget packages.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using as much self-contained testing as possible for an assembly before publishing a new package. Ideally, anything you would be putting into a NuGet package would be fully covered by unit tests and, if necessary, some kind of test app.

Also, if you're going to use NuGet, I would look at splitting up some of those assemblies if possible. It's easier to maintain references and track real updates to packages if they're in logically separated sets rather than one mega package.